# Can I tell /usr/lib/apt/methods/http to store its data elsewhere?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I don't have much space on my root partition. Sometimes I get warning as the free disk space plummets. I believe this is due to a couple of `/usr/lib/apt/methods/http` processes. The space gets mostly freed up again after a while but whatever this is doing, it brings me close to crashing things as the disk fills up.

What is this process doing?

Where is it storing data?

How can I tell it to store its data elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be to symlink /usr/lib/apt/methods/http to another directory on another disk. (In fact, you can symlink higher paths and move more off the small partition the same way)

Assuming you have another disk mounted at /data you could run something like

```
 mv /usr/lib/apt/methods/http /data/apt_methods_http
 ln -s /data/apt_methods_http /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
```

Comment: This is an answer to the question in your headline. Its probably not a great answer to the body of your question but probably not bad enough to delete.